# PHP randomize repeated string

Tags: php, unique

Could you please give me an example how to randomize the repeated string?

Below is my script, it generates a random string from 5-10. After that it gets repeated "1000" times and then I get a output like: "A1B2C3", "A1B2C3", "A1B2C3", but I want unique output like: "B1B3C2", "C3B1A2", "A3B1C2"

Could you please give me an example how to do it, because I am just a beginner and tried a lot before I asked here

```
<?php      

function generateRandomString() {
    return substr(str_shuffle('@*!"§$%&/()=?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'), 0, rand(5,10));
}       

while( 1 )
{
    $outstr = str_repeat(generateRandomString(), 1000);                                
    fwrite( $outstr );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `generateRandomString()` in a loop. You're just calling it once, passing that one string to `str_repeat`, and it then makes 100 copies of it.

```
$str = "";
for (i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $str .= generateRandomString();
}
echo $str;
```